# why isn't this array populated at the end of this function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following TypeScript function:

```
setSelectedTagsFilters(tags)
{
    //init return var
    var selectedTags = [];

    //set selected tags filters
    if (tags && tags.length > 0)
    {
        //required for parent context from for loop
        let that = this;

        //for each tag qs param
        for (let tag of tags)
        {
            //lookup matches
            var matches;
            if (isNumeric(tag)) matches = that.vm.AllTags.filter(x => x.id == tag);
            else matches = that.vm.AllTags.filter(x => x.text == tag);

            //if match then add to selectedTags
            if (matches.length == 0) selectedTags.push(matches[0]);
        }
    }
    //set the tag filters in batch
    this.setTagFilters(selectedTags);
}
```

I have a scenario where 2 matches are pushed to selected tags.  However, on the last line of code, selectedTags is an empty array.  Any idea why selectedTags is empty at the end of the method even though 2 objects where pushed to selectedTags in the for loop?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: This line looks like a problem: `if (matches.length == 0) selectedTags.push(matches[0]);`

Comment: @JohnnyHK what looks wrong with that line?  I have verified that on the line of code after the push, selectedTags is still empty.  but why?  and how can i fix?

Comment: Assuming `matches` is an array, that line says: if `matches` is empty, push its first (non existing) element into `selectedTags`.

Comment: As a suggestion, why don't you use curly braces with your if else  statements. That would make the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if (matches.length == 0) selectedTags.push(matches[0]);
```

is wrong. If `matches.length==0`, `matches[0]` is undefined, and also nothing gets pushed to `selectedTags`.

Try:

```
if (matches.length > 0) selectedTags.push(matches[0]);
```

instead.

Comment: yep i was getting lost in refactoring and typescript on a friday.  thanks!